# A generic term for a piece of writing

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a generic term which encompasses all types of work that a writer might do? Something that for example covers 'stories' and 'poems', but also 'articles' or 'journals'?

I thought possibly 'script', but I feel that as a script itself is a piece of written stageplay, in this context it doesn't feel generic enough.

Comment: 'Written works' is, I'd guess, the most idiomatic term for the oeuvre, but a one-word singular count usage (other than the fairly  rare 'a writing') evades me.

Comment: There are various terms but it will depend on the context. In literary criticism/theory you might see "text(s)", but on a CV/résumé I would use a different term (maybe "published writings"). It probably also depends on what you want to include/exclude: letters, proposals, shopping lists...

Answer (score 3):

***Writings***:

> the written works of a person:
>
> - *the writings of* Abraham Lincoln
>   ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/writings))

It is used in the plural to include any written work:

> *writings* PLURAL
> all the books etc that someone has written
>
> - Wordsworth’s *writings*
>   ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/writing))

Answer (score 0):

You may use **oeuvre** if you refer to most or all of a writer's output. It has overtones of authority that perhaps derive from its French origin or from its more general application to significant and substantial bodies of creative work such as musical composition, painting or sculpture, as well as to writing.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oeuvre)
>
> oeuvre, noun:
>
> a substantial body of work constituting the lifework of a writer, an artist, or a composer
>
> *"a catalogue of Rembrandt's oeuvre"
>
> "scrupulously examines Dickens' oeuvre in order to demonstrate how his convictions helped to determine the shape of his novels"*